# Got a little bit of a problem here when passing parameters thru react link, I`ve got "TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm calling a component through react link to, but together with that I need to pass a parameters.

I've tried all the solution here on the internet but still doesn't work

**ForgotPasswordComponent.js**

```html
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/user/forgotPassword/emailSent",
    state: [
      {
        email: this.state.email,
        subTitle: this.state.subTitle,
        title: this.state.title
      }
    ]
  }}
>
  <Button type="primary" className="send-button">
    Send
  </Button>
</Link>
```

and will try to receive the parameters using

**ForgotPasswordSuccessSentComponent.js**

```js
const { email, suhbTitle, title } = this.props.history.location.state;
```

To render the above component, I'm using a

**ForgotPassswordContainer.js**

```
import ForgotPasswordSuccessSentComponent from "./functions/ForgotPassswordSuccessSentComponent";

function renderSuccessPage() {
  return <ForgotPasswordSuccessSentComponent />;
}

export default class ForgotPasswordContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <Route
            path="/user/forgotPassword/emailSent"
            exact
            component={renderSuccessPage}
          />
        </div>
   );
  }
}
```

the output is :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ForgotPasswordContainer` you need to pass `ForgotPasswordSuccessSentComponent` as the component to the route itself.

```
export default class ForgotPasswordContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <Route
            path="/user/forgotPassword/emailSent"
            exact
            component={ForgotPasswordSuccessSentComponent}
          />
        </div>
   );
  }
}
```

The route props only get passed directly to the component that's passed to it and not the children components.

In your case, you were passing the function component, which is `renderSuccessPage`, which had `ForgotPasswordSuccessSentComponent` as the component it was rendering.

In the `ForgotPasswordComponent`, you need to pass an object to the state of the `Link` component, instead of an array of object.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/user/forgotPassword/emailSent",
    state: {
      email: this.state.email,
      subTitle: this.state.subTitle,
      title: this.state.title
    }
  }}
>
```

Comment: thank you, however currently it is not transferring any data/value to the component kindly see below code. Thank you

`const { email, subTitle, title } = this.props.history.location.state;`
`<Result
          status="success"
          title={title}
          subTitle={subTitle}
          extra={[
            <Button type="primary" key="console" href="/user/login">
              Back to login page
            </Button>
          ]}
        />`

Comment: You need to pass an object instead of an array of object as your state in the `Link` component in `ForgotPasswordComponent`. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

this a demo for what are you trying to do.
here if you try to navigate to the test page through the browser `URL` the component will not receive the state prop but when we click on the link we can now receive the state prop in the Test component.
here a sandbox for the code: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-newton-4khc6)

```
import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import "./styles.css";

    function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={main} />
              <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      );
    }

    const main = () => {
      return (
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: "/test",
            state: {
              email: "email",
              subTitle: "subtitle",
              title: "title"
            }
          }}
        >
          Go to test page
        </Link>
      );
    };

    const Test = props => {
      return (
        <div>{!props.history.location.state ? "not received" : "received"}</div>
      );
    };

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thank you for this one, I see you pass also an object instead of an array object. Cheers!

Comment: yes its the same as object but when you  try to access the array you need to pass index like this :`props.history.location.state[0].email` and you can check the sandbox again to see the result!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `array`,

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/user/forgotPassword/emailSent",
    state: [
      {
        email: this.state.email,
        subTitle: this.state.subTitle,
        title: this.state.title
      }
    ]
  }}
>
```

You need to pass `object` as,

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/user/forgotPassword/emailSent",
    state: {
        email: this.state.email,
        subTitle: this.state.subTitle,
        title: this.state.title
      }
  }}
>
```

You need to directly pass `ForgotPasswordSuccessSentComponent` as component like,

```
export default class ForgotPasswordContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <Route
            path="/user/forgotPassword/emailSent"
            exact
            component={ForgotPasswordSuccessSentComponent}
          />
        </div>
   );
  }
}
```

And finally to access values in `ForgotPasswordSuccessSentComponent` component, you need to wrap `ForgotPasswordSuccessSentComponent` component using [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) HOC like,

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class ForgotPasswordSuccessSentComponent extends React.Component{
   render(){
   const { email, suhbTitle, title } = this.props.history.location.state;
   console.log(email)   //Now you can access 
   return()
   }
}

export default withRouter(ForgotPasswordSuccessSentComponent)
```